# Ajax Axis2 communication issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, axis

I've been trying to get result from this Ajax command but only to end up with a failure

```
$.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "http://[localhost]:80**/*****/getdata.jws",
            data: 'method=s**&Table=empservice&Condition=%22ID_Service%22%3D'+$(this).val()+'',
            success: processSuccess, 
            error: processError
            });

    function processSuccess(data, status, req) {
    if (status == "success")
    alert("SUCCESS");
}

function processError(data, status, req) {
    alert("ERROR");
}  
        }


    });
```

This is supposed to call a jws web-service and return the XML result, I've tested the URL in the browser and it returns the wanted result XML ( the URL being url concatenated to "?" and data = http://[localhost]:80**/*****/getdata.jws?method=s**&Table=empservice&Condition=%22ID_Service%22%3D2) I've tried also to make a variable to get $(this).val() into it before the call but nothing works help please

ps: after the call I get the alert popup containing the "ERROR" message

ps2: you probably know it but I'll say it anyway [localhost] = localhost because the website do not allow localhost in a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, I need to use a proxy since AJAX calls are not allowed outside of one's domain

**if your domain is** localhost:80

a call from localhost:80 to localhost:8081 for example is not allowed

a call from localhost:80 to sdlksdlk.com is not allowed

only calls from localhost:80 to localhost:80 are allowed (in this example of course)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your error handler to something like this so you get more info than just "ERROR". This will write the actual error to the Firebug console. Also, take a look at the Firebug console to see what is actually being sent. I am assuming you aware I am referring to Firefox with the Firebug add-on.

```
error   : function(xhr, textStatus, error){
    console.log(xhr.statusText);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(error);
```

TD